# Laravel 5.4 - Insertar datos de Droplist y Checkbox en BD

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Ya tengo las migraciones de tres tablas, TABLA1: 'names' que contiene 'id' y 'name'. 
TABLA2: 'sports' que contiene 'id' y 'name', estas dos tablas ya contienen nombres y deportes. 
TABLA3: 'ids' contiene 'id', 'names_id' y 'sports_id', pero está vacía ya que quiero llenarla con los ids de las otras dos tablas.
Aquí está mi código.

SelectController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Sport;
use App\Name;

class SelectController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{

  $sports = Sport::all();
  $names = Name::all();
  return view('select', ['sports'=> $sports], ['names'=>$names]);

}
public function store(Request $request)
{

    //
}
}
```

select.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <title>Select name and sports</title>
<form action="/table" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  Elija un nombre:<br>
  <select name="names">
    <option value="">Nombre</option>
  @foreach($names as $name)
    <option value="{{ $name->id }}">{{ $name->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select><br><br>
  Elija los deportes que practica:<br>
  @foreach($sports as $sport)
  <input type="checkbox" class="form" name="sports" value="{{ $sport->id }}">{{ $sport->name }}<br>
  @endforeach
  <br><input type="submit" name="save" value="Guardar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Migraciones

Tabla 'names'

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateNamesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('names', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('names');
}
}
```

Tabla 'sports'

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSportsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('sports');
}
}
```

Tabla  'ids'

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateIdsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ids', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('names_id_');
        $table->string('sports_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('ids');
}
}
```

Comment: Hola. Si puedes copiar y pegar tu código facilitas que alguien aporte una solución. Las imágenes estan muy bien pero no nos permiten reproducir tu problema para hacer pruebas. En éste sentido puedes aportar tambien el código de las migraciones para generar las tablas afectadas. Luego entiendo que los datos que usaras para la tabla 3 proceden de las dos anteriores pero pasan por un formulario, ¿éste se genera correctamente? ¿puedes enviar el formulario y recoger los datos en el servidor? ¿cuál es el problema más concretamente?

Comment: Deja proporciono el código

Comment: Qué error te está mostrando?

Comment: No me marca ningún error, sólo no sé cómo insertar los datos del formulario de una droplist y un checkbox en la TABLA3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno te tengo una forma de hacerlo... no se si fuera la correcta pero te salva por lo pronto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <title>Select name and sports</title>
<form action="/table" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  Elija un nombre:<br>
  <select name="names">
    <option value="">Nombre</option>
  @foreach($names as $name)
    <option value="{{ $name->id }}">{{ $name->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select><br><br>
  Elija los deportes que practica:<br>
  @foreach($sports as $sport)
  <input type="checkbox" class="form" name="sports[]" value="{{ $sport->id }}">{{ $sport->name }}<br>
  @endforeach
  <br><input type="submit" name="save" value="Guardar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

solo cambie el name de sports a un array.
Ahora en el la ruta:

```
Route::post('table','TuControlador@laFuncion')
```

Y dentro del controlador haces esto:

```
public function laFuncion(Request $request){
    $names_id=$request->names;
    $sports_ids=$request->sports;
    foreach($sports_ids as $id){
        $ids=new TuModeloIds();
        $ids->names_id_=$names_id;
        $ids->sports_id=$id;
        $ids->save();
    }
    //hasta aqui todo guradado en adelante depende de ti
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

espero haber sido claro, y si te sirve no olvides marcar como respondida